# How to delete gatsby-starter-portfolio-cara file?

Tags: node.js, linux, gatsby

I have downloaded the gatsby-starter-portfolio-cara file from site and now I want to delete it. When I am trying to delete it, showed me an error that permission denied and cannot delete it. [Error while deleting the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRjuP.png) It also shows an lock icon. Can anyone tell me how to delete this file? I have nodejs 10.19 and npm 6.14.4

Comment: [DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) / [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Open the terminal and run:

```
sudo rm -rf gatsby-starter-portfolio-cara
```

Keep in mind that you will need to stop the related background running processes, for example, if you are running `gatsby develop`.